# how to remove spacing from left and right When mouse over on div

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hello Guys please check my issue:-

https://jsfiddle.net/wLewuhz4/

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 padding-0 myteam1">
    <div class="our-team">
        <img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2017/12/27/10/4797978100000578-0-image-a-1_1514370627819.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="myimage">
            <div class="team-content">
                <h3 class="team-title">First<small>class</small></h3>
                <p class="team-btn animate-button"><a href="#" class="custom-btn 
                btn-lg">LEARN MORE</a>
                </p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this when I mouse over the `div` then left and right space occur please help me how to fix this. I want full space remove and full background show when mouse over.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add [`overflow property`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) to `.myteam1`  `.myteam1{overflow:hidden;}`

> The overflow property specifies what happens if content overflows an
>   element's box.
>
> This property specifies whether to clip content or to add scrollbars
>   when an element's content is too big to fit in a specified area.

```css
.our-team {
  position: relative;
  margin: 35px 0;
}

.team-btn a {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.signup-subline {
  color: #fff;
}

.our-team img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  transition: all 0.20s ease;
}

.our-team:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.11, 1.11);
  z-index: 99999;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.our-team .team-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 13px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #2b2f3e;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  transition: all 0.20s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.padding-0 {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.our-team:hover .team-content {
  transform: translateY(46px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.our-team .team-title {
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.our-team .team-title small {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 1% 0 3% 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.our-team .social-link {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.our-team .social-link li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.our-team .social-link li a {
  color: #444;
  transition: all 0.50s ease;
}
.myteam1 {
overflow:hidden;
}
.myteam1:hover {
  z-index: 9;
}

.our-team .social-link li a:hover {
  color: #e143eb;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .our-team {
    margin-bottom: 15%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-6 padding-0 myteam1">
  <div class="our-team">
    <img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2017/12/27/10/4797978100000578-0-image-a-1_1514370627819.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="myimage">
    <div class="team-content">
      <h3 class="team-title">First<small>class</small></h3>
      <p class="team-btn animate-button"><a href="#" class="custom-btn btn-lg">LEARN MORE</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following css rule in your css file:

```
.our-team{ /*got this css from your jsfiddle*/
    position: relative;
    margin: 35px 0;
    overflow: hidden;    /*added this rule*/
}
```

Updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/wLewuhz4/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.padding-0 {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you want to remove left and right spacing from, black BG div, which appear on hover. Please add in your css, As i checked in your fiddle, it will fix your problem. - .body{margin:0;}